# Power Transfer for Sybase? - Trying to move data from Oracle to Sybase

Tags: oracle, etl, sap-ase

I need to move the data from  Oracle to Sybase. I have successfully moved the schema but to move data one of the white paper on Sybase pointed to use Power Transfer tool, however I cannot locate it on Sybase site. The whitepapers are bit old one in year 2000 and second one in 2006 so I wanted to know if Sybase has changed the name for Power Transfer or merged this with another software ? Anyone knows?

## Links for white paper

http://www.sybase.com/content/1032846/L02608_PowerTrans_WEB.pdf
http://www.sybase.com/content/1047976/MSSQL-ASE-Guide-111006-wp.pdf

Sorry this is my little project where I will DBA as well as Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind that I found the latest whitepaper which outlines to use BCP/ASCII files.

Here is the link if anyone need it in the future. 
http://www.sybase.com/files/White_Papers/ASE-Oracle-Migration-Guide-wp.pdf